# In Windows, Blender folder not in Start Menu for all users?

Tags: windows, installation

I have a Windows 7 computer with three users sessions.

But after installing Blender 2.77a, I noticed in the Start Menu that the Blender folder is not visible in other user session.

Is it normal ?

--- Update ---
Blender can be used in multi-user system ? Recent documents from an user is visible or not to other users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Blender's installation routine since I use Linux for 3D modeling for stability reasons (and regardless of the OS I tend to use the zipped version), but recently there was [a post of someone who claimed that it's exactly the other way round for 2.77b.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61184/why-are-blenders-icons-now-being-added-to-the-all-users-start-menu-and-not-t)

Regarding you "is it normal" question - as a former IT admin I'd say, if a software runs properly and the only issue is that some icons that are not "in place", it's normal (aka "happens every day"). Just move the Icons over to the "all users menu folder" and it's fixed.

If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Generally, we only prompt users to accept the answer as accepted if they remark that the answer solved their problem but they then didn't accept. This is generally done as a comment. I think it sounds a bit odd to add it into the answer as it presumes the user doesn't understand the process. More info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer

Comment: @RayMairlot, thanks for the hint, but the main reason for me to put that line under my posts is to prevent postings from getting pushed up again by the Community Process over and over again. We seem to have quite a lot of one-timers who ask their question and never come back even if they received a good answer. I'm planing to do a request on Meta in the near future about some things that in my opinion need to be improved (especially on BlenderSE). Until then I don't see why and how this line does any harm, even if a new user thinks I am begging for "likes".

Comment: I just think the body of an answer should be solely for answering the question. And I don't think it's just new users that will think its looks like 'begging'. I also think it may prompt a user to accept an answer before waiting for more (and potentially better) answers to be posted by other users. It's rushing the process.

Comment: .. Need more precision in the question, I edit and add more details in the question. Working or history from an user is visible to other user ?